# Where can I charge my laptop at SFO internationational terminal?

Tags: electronic-items, power, sfo

They have internet at SFO, but I am running out of battery. I have checked all the bars, but none seem to have outlets. Is there any way I can charge my gadgets while waiting for my flight?

Comment: Airside check the floor for outlets.  Plus if I remember they have charging stations.

Comment: A client of mine who worked his teenage summers in a hotel told me the thing to remember is that all these places need to be vacuumed. Start thinking like the person who has to plug in that vacuum, and you'll find the plugs.

Comment: @KateGregory: I've actually come across more than one airport that uses a custom style electrical plug/outlet for the vacuum cleaners etc presumably just so patrons can't plug in their devices!

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Sleeping in Airports review](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/usa/sanfrancisco.htm#.UmghBv6A0uQ), you can charge for a fee at

- Terminal 1, Boarding Area B near Gate 23
- Terminal 3, Boarding Area E near Gate 61
- Terminal 3, Boarding Area F near Gate 87

You might find free plugs elsewhere, but if you're desperate head on over and get charged up, then do more looking.

Answer (score 4):

Just found two desks at Gate A11 of the international terminal. You can work and charge at the same time.

While boarding I noticed yet two other desks where gear can be charged at gate A12

Answer (score 1):

Wander around the waiting areas near the gates.  There are a lot of empty ones and I've usually found some outlets there.